# $.formatNumber jquery API problem in IE

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I'm using a number formatter jquery library available here
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

I found a problem in IE while using this.

The following code

```
var number = "0.2343";
alert($.formatNumber(number, {format:"#,##0.00") );
```

returns 0.23 in firefox but .23 in IE
Could anyone tell me how I can get 0.23 in both the cases please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")
```

Comment: I think you are miss understand about this question. For example, if I use "12345.6789" as input, the result will be "12345,68" instead of "12,345.68". Another example, if I use "1234" as input, the result will be "1234" instead of '1,234.00".

Comment: you're right, I didn't understand. going to have to bow out on this, it's more work that I bargained for.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to change your library to jQuery Globalization plug-in(It's will be a part of jQuery core in version 1.5+). For more information, you can visit at the following link in ScottGu's Blog.

[jQuery Globalization Plugin from Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're formatting from a String, not from a number (float or double). Try changing the declaration to:

```
var number = 0.2343; //this is a double
```

or, if you can't modify that *String*, **parse it** to a *float* or *double*:

```
var number = parseFloat("0.2343"); //this is a float
```

Then try changing your format string to `",##0.00"`. It works for me:

```
alert($.formatNumber(number, {format:",##0.00") );
```